# How to bind QMessageBox button to action

Tags: c++, qt

I created a `QMessageBox` with Save, Discard and Cancel button:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.");
msgBox.setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
```

Now, how can I bind each of these buttons to a specific command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 QMessageBox msgBox;
 msgBox.setText("The document has been modified.");
 msgBox.setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?");
 msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
 msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
 int ret = msgBox.exec();

 switch (ret) {
   case QMessageBox::Save:
       // Save was clicked
       break;
   case QMessageBox::Discard:
       // Don't Save was clicked
       break;
   case QMessageBox::Cancel:
       // Cancel was clicked
       break;
   default:
       // should never be reached
       break;
 }
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing to open() and the finished(int) signal as well, for asynchronous/non-blocking use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need such bindings? The only thing you need is knowing which button of the message box was pressed to close it. You can get it with from the return value of `QMessageBox::exec()` function.

From the other hand, you can get the list of all buttons that are added to the message box, and use them to establish signal/slot connection(s):

```
QList<QAbstractButton *> buttons = msgBox->buttons();
foreach (QAbstractButton *btn, buttons) {
    connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onBtnClicked()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there are two ways you can achieve this. You can use `exec()` or you can use `show()` with `buttonClicked()` signal of message box.

It depends on your use case `exec()` is a blocking call. If you dont want your main application thread to be blocked you can use `msgBox.show()` and bind `buttonClicked()` signal of this message box to you custom slot using `connect()` function.

in case of `exec()` itsreturn code will tell you that which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

What is your implementation? Your case looks like you could just call the [static method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#question)

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton b = QMessageBox::question(QWidget* parent, "The document has been modified.", "Do you want to save your changes?", QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel, QMessageBox::Save);

if(b == QMessageBox::Save){
    ...
}else if(...){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QMessageBox::exec() returns the user's choice.

```
int val = msgBox.exec(); // val is now one of QMessageBox::Save, Discard or Cancel
```